# Node.js Readable self.push() stops after working 15 iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, readable

I am trying to understand why `Readable = require('stream').Readable` in this code only works 15 times on a node.js. I omit this line `X.on('data',function() {console.log('data')});` with this line it repeats indefinitely which is correct.

***start.js***

```
console.log('Start Therm');
const thermom = require('./therm.js');

var X = new thermom();
X._read();

X.on('start',function() {console.log('start')});

// X.on('data',function() {console.log('data')});

X.on('end',function() {console.log('end')});
X.on('error',function() {console.log('error')});
```

***therm.js***

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;  
var util = require('util');
var _ = require('lodash');
var count=0;
function getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(null, Math.round(Math.random() * 20 * 100)/100) 
  }, 10);
}


module.exports = Thermometer;

function Thermometer(options) {
  this.count = 0;
  if (! (this instanceof Thermometer)) {
    return new Thermometer(options);
  }
  if (! options) { 
    options = {};
  }
  options.objectMode = true;
  Readable.call(this, options);

}

util.inherits(Thermometer, Readable);


Thermometer.prototype._read = function read() {
  var self = this;

  getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer(
    function(err, temperature) {
    console.log('getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :' + temperature );
    if (err) { 
      self.emit('error', err);
    } else {
      console.log('self.push(temperature) :  ' +  count++);
      self.push();
    }
  });
};
```

node start.js  outputs just 15 iterations.

```
Start Therm
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :7.98
self.push(temperature) :  0
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :18.46
self.push(temperature) :  1
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :13.27
self.push(temperature) :  2
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :1.6
self.push(temperature) :  3
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :18.08
self.push(temperature) :  4
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :2.08
self.push(temperature) :  5
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :10.91
self.push(temperature) :  6
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :13
self.push(temperature) :  7
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :9.98
self.push(temperature) :  8
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :14.4
self.push(temperature) :  9
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :6.69
self.push(temperature) :  10
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :12.14
self.push(temperature) :  11
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :3.65
self.push(temperature) :  12
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :13.54
self.push(temperature) :  13
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :16.59
self.push(temperature) :  14
getTemperatureReadingFromThermometer :1.69
self.push(temperature) :  15
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the answer to this quandary.

```
 var X = new thermom({highWaterMark: 500 });
```

Would give you a buffer of 500 items in this queue, likewise a highWaterMark of 5 would reduce iteration to only 5. Its documented in node.js here https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_readable_options